# Define a drawing as an edge shape using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, texmaker

I have drawn this:

[image]

And my code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %1st rectangle
\draw (0,0) -- (0,5);
\draw (0,5) -- (6,5);
\draw (6,5) -- (6,0);
\draw (6,0) -- (0,0);
    %rectangle in 1st rectangle
\draw (1,3) -- (5,3);
\draw (5,3) -- (5,4);
\draw (5,4) -- (1,4);
\draw (1,4) -- (1,3);   
    %little square
\draw (2,3) -- (2,4);
\draw (3,3) -- (3,4);
\draw (4,3) -- (4,4);   
    %second rectangle
\draw (7,0) -- (7,5);
\draw (7,5) -- (13,5);
\draw (13,5) -- (13,0);
\draw (13,0) -- (7,0);
    %rectangle in 2nd rectangle
\draw (8,3) -- (12,3);
\draw (12,3) -- (12,4);
\draw (12,4) -- (8,4);
\draw (8,4) -- (8,3);   
    %little square
\draw (9,3) -- (9,4);
\draw (10,3) -- (10,4);
\draw (11,3) -- (11,4); 

\draw[thick,->](5,5) -- (8,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have numerous questions which are:

1. Is there any better way to achieve the drawing of a "rectangle" than drawing it manually line by line?
2. My final aim is to build a scheme with 4 of this rectangle where each are connected with arrows. Isn't there any way to define a rectangle as a shape and us it for a node of a graph? So i could easily link each of the rectangle.
3. If not: how could I draw all these arrows? With a correct bending (not as this one) and not a disguting style when all the arrows will be up.

Comment: You should to ask one question per post. For drawing rectangle use something like `\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only a partial answer as I am not sure I understand your 3rd point.

1. You can draw rectangles with the `rectangle` path construction.
2. If you want to draw the same thing multiple times, you can use `pics` for that.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
Kokodelo/.style={code={\begin{scope}[local bounding box=#1]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (6,5);
\draw (1,3) rectangle (5,4) foreach \X in {2,3,4} {(\X,3) -- (\X,4)};
\end{scope}
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic at (0,0) {Kokodelo=1};
\pic at (8,0) {Kokodelo=2};
\pic at (0,-8) {Kokodelo=3};
\pic at (8,-8) {Kokodelo=4};
\draw[thick,-latex] (1) to[bend left] (2);
\draw[thick,-latex] (3) to[bend right] (4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As mentioned above, I am not sure how to interpret your statements on the curved arrows, so I just added some.

Comment: Just what I wanted. For the 3rd point, i'm using anchors and it's working as expected. Thanks!